# Max size for keys in cassandra table with cfstats

Tags: cassandra, size, usage-statistics

**Problem:**

I would like to know the max size (and the average size) of the data for a partitionKey in a cassandra table.

**What I did so far:**

cfstats gives many information.

```
Keyspace: my_keyspace
        Read Count: 0
        Read Latency: NaN ms.
        Write Count: 1
        Write Latency: 0.289 ms.
        Pending Flushes: 0
                Table: my_table
                SSTable count: 1
                Space used (live): 63915
                Space used (total): 63915
                Space used by snapshots (total): 0
                Off heap memory used (total): 258
                SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.21345907193641897
                Number of keys (estimate): 24
                Memtable cell count: 13
                Memtable data size: 406
                Memtable off heap memory used: 0
                Memtable switch count: 0
                Local read count: 0
                Local read latency: NaN ms
                Local write count: 1
                Local write latency: 0,289 ms
                Pending flushes: 0
                Bloom filter false positives: 0
                Bloom filter false ratio: 0,00000
                Bloom filter space used: 176
                Bloom filter off heap memory used: 168
                Index summary off heap memory used: 50
                Compression metadata off heap memory used: 40
                Compacted partition minimum bytes: 925
                Compacted partition maximum bytes: 29521
                Compacted partition mean bytes: 12935
```

For the avg size I think "space used"/"number of keys" is the right thing to do.

But how to get more détails for each key ? (At least the max size)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot more statistics using Java VisualVM. You need to add a remote JMX connection to your cassandra nodes (default port is 7199). And then you go to `org.apache.cassandra.db/ColumnFamilies/my_keyspace/my_table`. There there is an attribute `LiveCellsPerSlice` that you may find usefull.

Answer (score 1):

`nodetool cfstats` gives a good summary output for tables in your schema. Often I will use this to compare values right across a cluster for a given table or keyspace for example to see if some nodes are holding a lot more keys than others or perhaps showing higher latencies. Then for the latter I could use `nodetool cfhistograms` to zoom in on that.

`space used` is just the space used for that table on that node, `number of keys` is an estimate of the number of partition keys that node holds from that table. For partition sizes it won't show the actual size for a given *key* but it will show the min / mean and max for partition keys in that table and this is what is often used to determine if your table has partitions that might have become too large for example.

The docs here talk more about cfstats:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsCFstats.html

`cfstats` is superseded by `tablestats` in Cassandra 3.0, the docs here give a good overview of what the fields means:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsTablestats.html?hl=tablestats